# Doing web.config transformations, but no way to test them

Tags: asp.net

I'm writing some transformations for my web config file.  But when I go to debug, is there a way to see the resulting web.config file?
I've tried http://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/; but I want to actually see what the web config file is while I'm debugging.

Comment: "but I want to actually see what the web config file is while I'm debugging." - how is that? What is the difference from just open the result file?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio 2012, the functionality is already there to right-click on your transform (say, Web.Release.config) and click "Preview Transform". If you're in VS2010 I don't think the functionality is there by default, but you can get it by installing the [Slow Cheetah extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5).